# Working of ServiceContract attribute in WCF

Tags: wcf, servicecontract

I just started reading about WCF. In the book the author has mentioned :

> The `ServiceContract` attribute maps a CLR interface/class as a WCF contract independently of that type's visibility.

How is this possible? The explanation given was:

> The type visibility has no bearing on WCF, because visibility is a CLR concept.

I really don't understand how this is possible. Can someone please explain?

Comment: I recognized the quote (I think) from Juval Lowy's book. I edited your question a bit, including a few minor updates to the quotes (using the book). Hopefully this improved the question, but if you feel I changed the semantics of your question for the worse feel free to revert my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of the type's *CLR visibility*, WCF can [retrieve attribute information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z919e8tw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to find out that in fact it's dealing with a *contract*, and similarly find out which *operations* that contract has. WCF can then decide to make that contract and its operations public (as in "publicize", not "CLR-public"), regardless of the CLR-visibility of the underlying type.

Note: Given the trend with ASP.NET and MVC, the [call for open sourcing WCF](http://aspnet.uservoice.com/forums/147206-wcf-web-services-/suggestions/2745145-open-source-the-whole-thing-so-i-can-decide-myself) may succeed at some time in the future. If that happens it may help to update this answer and add a link to or quote from the various implementations to further illustrate this.